# PPP connection not listed when using ICS

Tags: windows-7, pppoe, bridging

Using Windows 7.

I want to share a PPP connection called "T-Home DSL" with another computer on an ad hoc Wireless network. The connection is called "Wireless Internet Connection". I go to the adapter list and choose properties->Sharing on the Wireless Internet Connection. However, the only connections listed after checking the checkbox are: "Hamachi" and a "VirtualBox Host-Only Network", not the "T-Home DSL". I realize it isn't a totally normal connection (PPPoE) and it therefore might be unavailable, but I don't know how I can share the internet connection using it then. Maybe create some virtual LAN network adapter? How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the properties of the PPPoE connection first, then choose which interface ("Wireless Internet Connection") to make it available to.

Comment: I can't do that, since it tells me (in German) to use the "Netzmanager" when I try and open the Properties window.

Comment: Remove "Netzmanager". (Or play with the *nat* and *autodhcp* contexts in `netsh`.)